# NodeJS Script is crashing after sending 5 Requests from Chrome

Tags: node.js

I have an problem, where my node script is crashing after sending 5 requests from my browser. The goal is to update Database fields with the correct values sent to the script via react. The following code represents an example for the UPDATE request on my node script.

```
app.put("/updateOffCity", (req, res) => {
const value2 = req.body.value2;
const value1 = req.body.value1;
db.query("UPDATE test_table SET test_field = ? WHERE number = ?", [value1, value2], (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
})
});
```

The error was i never sent an response back to the browser meaning, my open requests where never finished and Chrome can only handle 5 open requests at once.

Following code is the correct one:

```
app.put("/updateOffCity", (req,res) => {
const value2 = req.body.value2;
const value1 = req.body.value1;

db.query("UPDATE test_table SET test_field = ? WHERE number = ?", [value1, value2], (err, result) => {
  if(err) {
   console.log(err);
  } else {
   console.log(result);
  }
 });
  res.send("update done");
 });
```

Comment: How is it "crashing"?  What is the actual error when it fails?

Comment: its like a crash i cant perform any updates. meaning the updated fields in the app are not shown in the db as if like the script is not working.

Comment: Since you are aleady checking `if (err)`, mind to tell us if and what error is printed? But on a first glance: You are not sending any response from your request ...

Comment: okay so in my terminal in vsc it says nothing thus i dont know actually where to check for that incoming err because when im on the node page it says cannot get /

Comment: @Jimanuelson: "its like a crash" doesn't really add much detail to the original assertion of "[it's] crashing".  You need to find out what the actual error is.  A step debugger in your IDE would be ideal, but failing that you can always add more `console.log` statements and observe the output on the server-side console.  Is an error from the query operation being logged to the console?  Can you confirm that the query operation is being performed at all?  Can you confirm that the PUT operation is being invoked at all?  What response is being received client-side?

Comment: i can perform 5 of the same queries before its not updating the query is working and its updating but as soon as i do the sixth its not working/updating

Comment: @Jimanuelson: *"in my terminal in vsc it says nothing"* - Not even the output from `console.log(result);`?  Are you looking in the right place for Node console output?  *"cannot get /"* - Is this causing the *client-side* code to fail and stop sending requests?  Or is the client still sending further requests, after receiving successful responses for the first 5 requests, and receiving failed responses for all later requests?  Please *be specific*, we can't see your screen from here.

Comment: aight aight so when i open the page for the first time without sending any requests it says cannot get /. the same for accesing the site after doing an update.

when i update it says okpacket with all the props and the message contains rows matched: 1 changed: 1 warnings: 0 this is for the first 5 after the fifth there is no message in my terminal related to updating or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. The problem was that i never sent an Response to the request. So i had 5 open requests which were not finalized and finished.